# xPath to get sibling value for element with specific value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Given this XML:

```
<InitResponse>
  <LottoToken>908ec70b308adf10d04db1478ef9b01b</LottoToken>
  <GameInfoList>
    <GameInfo>
      <Draw>
        <gameId>L649</gameId>
        <draw>3035</draw>
      </Draw>
    </GameInfo>
    <GameInfo>
      <Draw>
        <gameId>BC49</gameId>
        <draw>2199</draw>
      </Draw>
    </GameInfo>
  </GameInfoList>
</InitResponse>
```

I need to get the draw number based on a specific gameId.  For example if I specify gameID L649 I need to get 3035.

The following works in several online evaluators, but not in C#.  It says it cannot find it.  Suggestions?

```
/InitResponse/GameInfoList/GameInfo/Draw/draw[preceding-sibling::gameId='L649']
```

C# Code I've tried:

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/InitResponse/GameInfoList/GameInfo/Draw/draw[preceding-sibling::gameId='L649']");
```

... where xmlDoc is an xmlDocument object loaded with the xml. the node variable ends up with a null value which seems to indicate there was no match found.

Comment: You should use `XPath`

Answer (score 5):

Here is xpath (with Linq)

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
string xpath = "/InitResponse/GameInfoList/GameInfo/Draw[gameId='L649']/draw";
var draw = xdoc.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
if (draw != null) // check if draw with gameId found in xml
    value = (int)draw;
```

Also you can use pure Linq to Xml (but in this case xpath looks more compact):

```
var draw = xdoc.Descendants("GameInfo")
               .SelectMany(g => g.Elements("Draw"))
               .SingleOrDefault(d => (string)d.Element("gameId") == "L649");
if (draw != null)
    value = (int)draw.Element("draw");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using XmlDocument**

I didn't saw something wrong in your `XPath` statement, look on the following:

(So i guess there is something else that is wrong)

```
XmlDocument myDoc = new XmlDocument();

String str = @"<InitResponse>
                 <LottoToken>908ec70b308adf10d04db1478ef9b01b</LottoToken>
                     <GameInfoList>
                         <GameInfo>
                             <Draw>
                               <gameId>L649</gameId>
                               <draw>3035</draw>
                              /Draw>
                            </GameInfo>
                            <GameInfo>
                              <Draw>
                                <gameId>BC49</gameId>
                                <draw>2199</draw>
                              </Draw>
                            </GameInfo>
                          </GameInfoList>
                        </InitResponse>";

            myDoc.LoadXml(str);

            XmlNode node =
                myDoc.SelectSingleNode("/InitResponse/GameInfoList/GameInfo/Draw/draw[preceding-sibling::gameId='L649']");
```

The node which returns from the result is: 3035

**Note:** your first note have to be `<InitResponse>` otherwise it will returns null